# How to change email subject in C# using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

I have a piece of code where I am connecting via Exchange Web Services, and I have the message ID.  I need to change the subject of this email to the string passed into my method for successful processing later in my workflow.  However, I am a bit confused as to how to use the exchange web services classes, my code is below:

```
public bool SetEmailCorrectSubject(string msgID, string subject)
{
    bool bSuccess = true;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(msgID))
    {
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        ItemIdType messageId = new ItemIdType();
        messageId.Id = msgID;

        ItemChangeDescriptionType desc = new ItemChangeDescriptionType();
        // Not sure how to set this up
        ItemChangeType itemChange = new ItemChangeType();
        itemChange.Item = messageId;
        UpdateItemType updateItem = new UpdateItemType();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error("error with resending email with title", e);
        return false;
    }
    return bSuccess;
}
```

From what I understand, the UpdateItemType class is the way to go, but I'm not clear on how to tell it that I want to change the email subject to the subject parameter.

Any ideas?  Is using UpdateItemType even the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of EWS you should use the EWS Managed API as it's more simple to use:

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480

EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx

Apart from that, you don't use the ItemChangeType and UpdaetItemType to modify items. Use the Item.Bind() method to bind to the item, change the subject and update it:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
                      {
                          UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                          Url = new Uri("https://casserver/ews/exchange.asmx")
                      };
Item item = Item.Bind(service, new Itemid(msgid));
item.Subject = "test";
item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

Btw, are you sure you have the ItemId? Or do you have an RFC 822 Message-Id? Those two are different.

Comment: What is the difference: ***ItemId vs RFC 822 Message-Id***?

Comment: The ItemId is a binary identifier generated by Exchange which can be used to access the item. The Message-Id is usually generated by the one creating the mail (or the first mail server which handles the mail).